# implementing transactions in c# ASP.NET Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactions, ado.net

I'm writing a program that takes a webservice that gives many records.
I wanted to implement a transaction so that if ever there will be an error, the "inserted" records will be rolled back.
Here is my code but it is not working. 
Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
string findID = "SELECT e.ID, e.SchoolYearTermsID, e.StudentID, e.DegreeProgramID, e.YearLevelID, syt.SchoolYear, syt.Term FROM ENROLLEES e INNER JOIN SCHOOLYEARTERMS syt ON syt.SchoolYearTermsID = e.SchoolYearTermsID INNER JOIN STUDENTS s ON e.StudentID=s.StudentID WHERE syt.TERM = @term";
            string strcom = "SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE StudentID = @id";
            string addEnrollee = "INSERT INTO ENROLLEES VALUES(@sytid, @studid, @degprogid, @yrlvlid)";


        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.strcon2);
        connection.Open();

        SqlTransaction transaction;
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
                int insert = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dtb.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    int id = int.Parse(dtb.Rows[i]["StudentID"].ToString());
                    string term = GlobalData.term;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcom, connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    bool ean = dr.HasRows;
                    if (dr.HasRows == true)
                    {
                        //add
                        dr.Close();
                        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(findID, connection);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);
                        SqlDataReader d = com.ExecuteReader();

                        if (d.HasRows == false)
                        {
                            d.Close();
                            dr.Close();
                            SqlCommand add = new SqlCommand(addEnrollee, connection, transaction);

                            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sytid", dtb.Rows[i]["SchoolYearTermsID"].ToString());
                            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studid", dtb.Rows[i]["StudentID"].ToString());
                            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@degprogid", dtb.Rows[i]["DegreeProgramID"].ToString());
                            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yrlvlid", dtb.Rows[i]["YearLevelID"].ToString());
                            insert++;
                            GlobalData.insertRec = insert;
                            d.Close();
                            dr.Close();

                            add.Transaction = transaction;
                            add.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        dr.Close();
                        d.Close();
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
                transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
                transaction.Rollback();

        }

        finally
        {
                connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Any exception?

Comment: hmm it doesnt add the records i dont know why..

Comment: It can't just simply do nothing, if there's an error, it will throw an exception. We can't help you without understanding of what's wrong.

Comment: i tried executing it and there was no error or an exception thrown. so im really confused. im thinking that there's some kinda semantic error that i cant see..

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging it? As you aren't catching any exception or logging it, chances are your transaction is just rolled back

Comment: i changed the catch into catch(SqlException ex) and there was an error saying:

Comment: ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

Comment: If it's executing without error, and nothing is happening on the dB data landscape, that tells me that your selectuon/target is faulty.   If I tell the dB to update the address of all ppl named George, and none get changed.... I make sure I'm not targeting it wrong "geeeeoege" as an example.   Debug breakpoint and walk through the steps and check variables as it's in paused state to be sure it's still doing as you think it should be.

Comment: @ShamvilU.Gases so you need to deal with this error to make your code work